# My online work is posted under an alias, how do I present that on my resumé?

Tags: resume, hiring-process, recruitment, online-presence

My last name is weird and unpronounceable in my country's language, and I'm undergoing a name change procedure, which can take many years.

Now, legally I still have that old name, but all my online content (blog and personal domain, SE profile, etc) is under my new name, how do I put that on my resumé so it doesn't look strange nor fishy to potential employers ?

Let's say my legal name is still John Smith (the name change isn't effective yet), that name is the name I use on my resumé but I send my job application emails from `johndoe.com`, and on that resumé is a link to my blog `johndoe.com`, how should I mention that in my application email or résumé ?

*Note that for privacy reasons I'd rather not mention that fact nor my old name on my site.*

Comment: In india an affidavit to the effect that <old name> and <new name> son of<fathers name> resident of <address> are one and same person, could be produced.

Answer (score 24):

Your problem isn't uncommon. Many people who marry change their surname to that of their partner, and in the 21st century this does no longer only apply to women. So staff managers are used to checking references of people who were once known under a different name.

Just state your name in your résumé as *"John Doe (born: John Smith)"*. That way it should be obvious to everyone that John Smith and John Doe are the same person.

Comment: Perfect example of `Keep It Simple Stupid`

Comment: Just to make it explicit: no need to mention your old name in your application email.

Answer (score 5):

1. List the links to your online content in your resume. Don't let the fact that you are using an alias bother you.
2. Mention that you are listing your online content under the more English-friendly name "John Smith" in your cover letters and that you are identifying yourself under your legal name in the "About" section
3. Create an "About" section for your online content and you say who you are - and use your legal name there.

That should take care of this business.