# Should I change my teenage username for a new one?

Tags: email

Since I was about 12, I am using an username, with this username I signed up in a lot of pages, posting about everything, except politics, porn, racism, etc. I got some designs saved with this username and a project that I made for the degree in my github's account.

Now I am almost finishing my degree and I am thinking that maybe what I did in my adolescence makes some negative points to the interviewers or maybe some positive I don't know.

If I must to change the username another questions appear. The new username would have to be my real name or another nickname? And if my degree's project is under the github of my actual username I must to change the ownership to the new username? I've seen [What should a professional email address look like?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/11731/what-should-a-professional-email-address-look-like) but it isn't what I am looking for.

Comment: Why not create a new account for professional use instead of using one account for everything

Comment: I don't understand why you have to *change* the username. I'll assume you have a github account under `awesomename1234` or something like that. And now you want to demonstrate those projects for professional purposes. Why not just post it now again under your new name? If they are open source already you can mention if you want somewhere that you published them previously under a screen name.

Comment: GitHub allow changing username: https://help.github.com/articles/changing-your-github-username/

Comment: possible duplicate of [My online work is posted under an alias, how do I present that on my resumé?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/36488/my-online-work-is-posted-under-an-alias-how-do-i-present-that-on-my-resum%c3%a9)

Comment: Is the problem the name or the things you have posted under that name.  There are plenty of interesting usernames out there being used by professionals, just take a look at some of the names on the various StackExchange sites.

Comment: By all means change your github username to something other than bikinibandit. I have a couple of email addresses as well, one for professional stuff and another for random stuff. I think most people I know do the same thing.

Comment: @gnat The article you linked is talking more about legally changing one's name. This one here is more about the Internet-specific practice of using screen names for one's activities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It really depends on the name.

I did exactly what you are considering, a few years back. I wanted to have a username that I could say out loud on the workfloor without getting weird faces. I'm glad I did, but I'm not entirely sure it was necessary. A username is not like an email address. You put your mail address on your resume, and on your business card.

The most important reason you could have for changing an online username, is so that when a hiring manager decides to look you up on Google they don't find you under 'YourMomSoHot1993'. Mine wasn't that shameful so I suppose I could've held on to it.

Answer (score 0):

The new user id could be either your real name or another nickname. Companies won't be surprised by either. Your employer will probably assign you a company e-mail account after hiring you (and may or may not let you pick your own name).

(I've been using a synthetic nickname for many decades...)